# Performance test across microservice in Docker

Tags: performance, docker, microservices, performance-testing

Suppose I have two microservices hosted in two different docker container. I want to compute the duration of a response from a service to another. For instance,

service1:
-record startTime
-do some computation
-send response, startTime to service2

service2:
-receives response
-do some computation
-record endTime
-compute the duration: endTime - startTime

I would like to know if the above strategy is a good approach? Does container have different time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the container may hove different time maybe due to next reasons:

- The 2 container not in same machine, and the machines's time may be not correct, maybe not align with NTP, or just because of different time zones.
- 1 container may mount `/etc/localtime`, while another did not mount it.

So, maybe 3 options here:

1. If you can control, make all containers time same.
2. Let `container2` send back `startTime` again to `container1`, let some process in `container1` to record `endTime`, then do the calculate in same container.
3. If you do not care the time cost from container1 to container2. Then, in container1, you could just calculate the time duration in container1 to container2, not send the startTime. Then in container2, you could plus this duration.